# How to solve "XmlRpcTypeMismatchException " in C#

Tags: c#, automation, xml-rpc

I am using automation tool to automate Android application. The tool provides C# code which I can add in my C# project.

I am using one API of that tool. It is throwing an exception

> *XmlRpcTypeMismatchException: response contain struct value where string expected*

How can I solve this issue? API should return `string` according to documentation of automation tool.

Sample Code

```
//Set the client to interact with Automation tool

client = new Client(host, port);

//Set the android device

client.SetApplicationTitle(activeDevice);

//Call automation tool API HybridRunJavascript( Webview, index , Javascript) to execute Javascript . This is mocking the App object 

string str0 = client.HybridRunJavascript("", 0, "AppObj.set(null, 0.1, true, true);");
```

Comment: Would you please post a code sample? It would help very much.

Comment: /*Set the client to interact with Automation tool
Set the android device
Call automation tool API HybridRunJavascript( Webview, index , Javascript) to execute Javascript . This is mocking the App object */

client = new Client(host, port);

client.SetApplicationTitle(activeDevice);

string str0 = client.HybridRunJavascript("", 0, "AppObj.set(null, 0.1, true, true);");

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: What is the type of `Client`? You said that is an Android client? What assembly does `client` come from?

Comment: It is a DLL which we got from automation tool package. We included that in our project. - Thanks Sindhu

Answer (score 0):

Just change the return value of the method definition from XmlRpcStruct to String.

Before:

```
XmlRpcStruct myMethod(...params...);
```

After:

```
String myMethod(...params...);
```